# Most time efficient route

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm to make a pathfinding tool. I believe, it is not exact salesman problem due to different nature of desired result.

Main goal is to build route through multiple points to visit more points in less time. It does not require to include all points into route, just opposite: if visiting a point or a group of points makes big detour, it is not worth including into route, as point/distance ratio would drop significantly.

Conditions:

- there will always be starting point A (chosen by user), but finish can be back in point A, can be in point B or can be undefined to end route when visiting any more points would decrease efficiency
- total pool of points (chosen by user) ranges from tens to thousands depending on filter
- points can have weights to define how much visiting them contributes
- app has to be more or less real time: user needs to get result within few minutes from entering starting conditions

To decrease waiting times I can make two optimizations: merge nearby points by distance into one point with increased weight and limit visitable points by certain radius from A or AB vector.

Bruteforce method does not work with big numbers, and popular pathfinding algorithm A* does not seem to be applicable here as well from what I understood. I thought about using ant algorithm or looking into other genetic algorithms, but is there any existing algorithm/method specifically made for such task? Also what (if any) further optimizations could be made to the pool of points for better results?

My approach so far (JavaScript). Scenarios 2 and 3 include distance to finish point as well.

```js
let maxRatio = 0
let bestRoute = []
for (let path of allPaths) {
    let distance = 0
    let weight = 0
    let currentPosition = {x: 0, y: 0}

    for (let point of path) {
        distance += getDistance(currentPosition, point)
        weight += point.weight
        currentPosition.x = point.x
        currentPosition.y = point.y
    }
    if (weight / distance > maxRatio) {
        maxRatio = weight / distance
        bestRoute = path
    }
}
```

With 2 sets of starting conditions (difference only in last point)

```js
// input 1
[
    {x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2},
    {x: 15, y: 14, weight: 1},
    {x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1},
    {x: 30, y: 30, weight: 2},
]
// input 2
[
    {x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2},
    {x: 15, y: 14, weight: 1},
    {x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1},
    {x: 30, y: 30, weight: 4},
]
```

Scenario 1, from point A (0:0) to the end of route:

```
// output 1.1
Best weight/distance ratio: 0.15207666105559417 
at visiting order [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1 },
  { x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2 },
  { x: 15, y: 14, weight: 1 }
]
```

Here we can see that one point, 30:30 with weight 2, is not included into the best route because it is simply too far away.

```
// output 1.2
Best weight/distance ratio: 0.16754421339617698 
at visiting order [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1 },
  { x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2 },
  { x: 15, y: 14, weight: 1 },
  { x: 30, y: 30, weight: 4 }
]
```

Here we can see that point, 30:30 with weight 4 now, being included into the best route because visiting it benefits us.

Scenario 2, from point A (0:0) back to point A (0:0):

```
// output 2.1
Best weight/distance ratio: 0.07699655016791247 
at visiting order [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 15, y: 14, weight: 1 },
  { x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2 },
  { x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1 },
  { x: 0, y: 0 }
]
```

Different order or points this time, but still furthest point not included

```
// output 2.2
Best weight/distance ratio: 0.08469183439702697 
at visiting order [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 15, y: 14, weight: 1 },
  { x: 30, y: 30, weight: 4 },
  { x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2 },
  { x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1 },
  { x: 0, y: 0 }
]
```

And here, with weight 4, we include it.

Scenario 3, from point A (0:0) to point B (10:10):

```
// output 3.1
Best weight/distance ratio: 0.12459750581354255 
at visiting order [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1 },
  { x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2 },
  { x: 10, y: 10 }
]
```

Here optimal route became shorter

```
// output 3.2
Best weight/distance ratio: 0.12459750581354255 
at visiting order [
  { x: 0, y: 0 },
  { x: 6, y: 8, weight: 1 },
  { x: 10, y: 12, weight: 1.2 },
  { x: 10, y: 10 }
]
```

But even with weight 4 on (30:30) point we do not include it.

Comment: Do you have a working code sample (even brute-force), or can you define what you're optimizing a route on more rigorously? Are you looking for just the largest weight/distance ratio? A small example (and your expected output) could help make the problem clearer.

Comment: Have you read about [vehicle routing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem)? Is it applicable to your case?

Comment: @kcsquared yes, best weight/distance ratio. Updated with examples.

Comment: @Aivean yes, seems so, but only for one of my three scenarios, for number 2. Does it work for other two scenarios as well? Does it work with up to thousands points to choose from?

Comment: So far, your problem still looks like a variant of traveling salesman. Question: do you allow vertices and/or edges to be visited multiple times on your path (if it yields better cost)?

Comment: @Aivean each vertex can be visited multiple times, but only first visit increases score.